# Having trouble with MySQL and fs.writeFile (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, fs, node-mysql

I'm having some trouble with Node JS MySQL and fs.
What I'm trying to do, is extracting data from my database to a local `txt` file.
For each ID in the database, I want it to go a line down like `\n`

My code:

```
 connection.query(`SELECT * FROM appmsg`, function(error, results, fields) {
      try{
          fs.writeFile('./commands/utils/apps.txt', JSON.stringify(results.join("\n")), function (err) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("Saved!");
          })

        }
        catch(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
      })
```

In the `txt` file:

`"[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]\n[object Object]"`

Looking forward to a response.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(results).join(",\n")` try this,

Comment: @CodeBug `JSON.stringify(results).join(",\n")` it can't work because `JSON.stringify()` will return string. so you can't use `.join()` with string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `results.map(result => JSON.stringify(result)).join("\n")` instead of `JSON.stringify(results.join("\n"))`.

This issue because you convert the array to string `results.join("\n")`. so when you convert array to string he will convert each object to string so it will be `[object Object]`. you need to convert each object to JSON then convert all array to string. to can save data as you need.